# Overriding Link Colors in a DIV

Tags: html

I am having a very difficult time in overriding the link colors within a DIV.  No matter what I do I end up with the default link colors of the CSS.  I just don't get it.  Thank you in advance - any ideas?

At the bottom of my CSS I have added:

```
#retpopups a:link{
color:#CC0000; !important
background-color:transparent; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-weight:bold
},
a:visited {
color:#7b3333; !important
background-color:transparent; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-weight:bold
},
a:hover {
color:#f55c5c; !important
background-color:transparent; 
font-weight:bold
},          
a:active { 
color:#00527a; !important
background-color:transparent; 
text-decoration:underline; 
font-weight:bold
```

HTML:

```
<div id="retpopups" align="center">
<table width="32%" border="0" align="center"title="Data Available">
<tr>`enter code here`
<td>
<a href="#"onclick="MM_openBrWindow
('images/grandview/retail/grandview_rendering.pdf',
'GrandViewRendering','toolbar=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,
resizable=yes,width=600,height=600')">
Rendering</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="#"onclick="MM_openBrWindow
('images/grandview/retail/grandview_aerial.pdf',
'Aerial','toolbar=yes,location=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,
width=600,height=600')">
Aerial View</a>             
</td>
```

Comment: Your code works fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMzZgZ

Comment: You should tag this with CSS so that the code highlighting works.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem - The hover doesn't work.

Comment: i tried in codepen and it looks fine-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZNEBM

Comment: I don't know why no one else is able to reproduce the error but you need to remove those commas you have after the closing braces. You don't need them and hover will work once you take them out.

Comment: @NagaSaiA - The hover doesn't work in your pen either.

Comment: Yes removing commas, making all the anchor tag css are working

Comment: Updated codepen -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZNEBM

Answer (score 0):

first of all, !important needs to be inside of the style (color:#ff0000 !important;) Fixed that and the comma use and it worked fine!

```
#retpopups a:link{
color:#CC0000;
background-color:transparent; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-weight:bold
}
#retpopups a:visited {
color:#7b3333;
background-color:transparent; 
text-decoration:none; 
font-weight:bold
}
#retpopups a:hover{
color:#09f;
background-color:transparent; 
font-weight:bold;
}         
#retpopups a:active { 
color:#00527a;
background-color:transparent; 
text-decoration:underline; 
font-weight:bold;
}
```